# Efficient way of creating numerous factory objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, factory-method

I'm tasked with a graphical menu system that is built on a wheel navigation model where each 'layer' of menu is composed of a new Wheel object with properties that define colors and menu choices and so on.

I'd like to use a Factory method to build a single generic object creator for building all the layers, something akin to the dog factory from Mattias Petter Johansson at funfunfunctions:  video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImwrezYhw4w transcript: https://medium.com/humans-create-software/factory-functions-in-javascript-video-d38e49802555#.mrrvx4a37

Dog object as Factory method:

```
const dog = () => {
  const sound = 'woof'
  return {
    talk: () => console.log(sound)
  }
}

// create a single new dog
const sniffles = dog()  
sniffles.talk() // Outputs: "woof"
```

This works well, and I get how it works.  What stumps me a bit is how to 'mass create' about 30 more dogs from say...looping through an array of dog names with mutable properties (different color, size, etc).

Any tips or examples or directions to look are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very quick half-written example, I'll leave filling the rest as an exercise to the reader:

```
const dogProps = [{color: "brown"}, {color: "black"}];
const dog = ({color}) => {
  // construct with color
};

const dogs = dogProps.map(dog);
```

Comment: Thanks, Madara for the quick response!  But if I get your code, I would access each of the dogs colors via dogs[1].color, dogs[2].color, etc.   What if I wanted to access them via more personal names... sniffles.color, scruffy.color and so on...  using an array to generate the name of the object too.  ?

Comment: @JimmPratt There are no variable variables in JS. You can use destructuring assignment like so: `const [sniffles, scruffy] = dogProps.map(dog)`. But you can't define new variable on an inner scope with a dynamic name.

Comment: Meh, thought as much... and using eval() is considered evil...and using dogNames = ["sniffles", "scruffy"); using the window['varname'] method feels messy in trying to add methods and variables (http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/dynamic-variables-in-javascript/).. so... ok,  will live with dogs[i].whatever.   Thanks for your time!